# android SimpleCursorAdapter in AsyncTask caught error

Tags: android, android-asynctask, simplecursoradapter

I don't know why encounter error when I'm trying to add SimpleCursorAdapter in AsyncTask .

```
 private class LoadNewsLists extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {
     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {         
     }


     @Override
     protected Cursor doInBackground(final String... args) {
         Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchMainActivity();
         return cursor;
     }


     protected void onPostExecute(final Cursor cursor) {
         String[] columns = new String[] {
                  DatabaseUtil.rtitle,
                  DatabaseUtil.rtypeof
          };

          // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
          int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.idTitle,
            R.id.idType
          };

          // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
          //as well as the layout information
          dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.listhome,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

          listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
          listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);          
     }
```

when I render above coding then I encountered following errors.

```
06-07 09:14:33.496: E/AndroidRuntime(21735): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 09:14:33.496: E/AndroidRuntime(21735):    
at com.ppshein.test.MainActivity$LoadNewsLists.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check at dbHelper instance. It is probably null, meaning that this line, will through a NPE:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchMainActivity();
```

Comment: what a crap...! Thanks. I forgot to init dbHelper.